# entering a record as a procedure, it succeeds, but there is no record in the tables,

Tags: sql

When I execute a record while entering a record as a procedure, it succeeds, but there is no record in the tables, what should I do?

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Hastayikayıtedelim](

@Ad nvarchar(50),
@Soyadı nvarchar(100),
@TcKimlik nchar(11),
@DogumTarihi date,
@TelefonNo nvarchar(11)
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
  Insert Into Hastalar(Ad,Soyadı,TcKimlik,DogumTarihi,TelefonNo)
  values (@Ad,@Soyadı,@TcKimlik,@DogumTarihi,@TelefonNo)
  exec Hastayikayıtedelim 'EmSir','YilZmaz','43924717343','1996.20.05','05533326789'
  
 END
```

Comment: Do you commit? Show us your code, and add a <tag> for the dbms used.

Comment: I add right now

Comment: You should exec Hastayikayıtedelim from the outside. (I.e. move that row to after `END`.)

Comment: I add from the outside but error  he INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Hastalar_Testler". The conflict occurred in database "hastane", table "dbo.Testler", column 'TestID'.

Comment: Great, you're half the way now!

Comment: The error message indicates you're trying to INSERT a value into Hastalar that does not exist in the Testler table's Testler column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is the following command, after you have executed your alter statement, into your script :

COMMIT;